ActiveMQ Artemis support for Jakarta and JDK 17
We have an application based on Spring 5 that uses ActiveMQ Artemis 2.30.0 with JDK 11. We are now migrating to Spring 6, which requires the Jakarta namespace and JDK 17. Is ActiveMQ Artemis compatible with the Jakarta namespace and JDK 17? If so, which version of Artemis should we use for this migration?

What the documentation and release notes say?

Artemis provides Jakarta artifacts already in 2.30. It should run on java 17 as it is built on 11.
